# Is a projective space a vector space? If not, what of a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

A projective space is not a vector space, correct?  At a minimum, there is no additive identity in a projective space.

So can you even have a basis of a projective space?  $[1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1]$ might work for $P^3$.  Or are $[1 0 0]$ and $ [0 1 0]$ not linearly independent since they both lie on the line at infinity?

(is there a "too much" span problem with $[0 0 0]$ as well?)

If not, is there a roughly analogous concept for a projective space?

Comment: How do you define sum of two points? Note for instance that $$(0:2:0) = (0:3:0)$$ (in homogeneous coordinates) but $$ (1:0:0) + (0:2:0) = (1:2:0) \ne (1:3:0) = (1:0:0) + (0:3:0)$$ so addition is not well-defined.

Comment: What does it mean to have a basis in a space in which there is no such thing as addition, nor any notion of scalar multiplication?

Comment: Google for "projective frame".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps it would be illustrative to demonstrate what happens with $\mathbb P^1$ (say over the real numbers). You might think about this as the set of lines in $\mathbb R^2$. Now, rather than thinking in terms of numbers, draw a picture or two. What could it reasonably mean to "add" two lines in $\mathbb R^2$ and expect to get a line back?

Perhaps a more convincing argument is this. Remember that a vector space is not just saying "hey I have a basis". It needs to remember that its a group. So in particular, you need an identity. You've thrown out $(0,0)$ remember, this is not an element of $\mathbb P^1$. But now anything you pick is going to run into the same problem that the comments as above described. You cant write down a meaningful statement like: $(a:b)+id = (a:b)$ and expect it to be true, because $id$ could be scaled to mess up your arithmetic.

See the comments above for other examples.

Comment: OK.  Thank you.  Could you set up Pn as two vector spaces?  One for the hyperplane at infinity and one for everything else?  You might be able to define addition as "convert to Euclidean, add, convert back from Euclidean".  Then the additive identity would be [0 0 1] for the "non-line at infinity" vector space par.

Comment: To provide context, I am trying to follow a paper that discusses an "orthonormal basis of displacement vectors"